# Wrong Result With Trigonometric Pendulum Problem

Tags: trigonometry

$P(t)$ models the distance of a swinging pendulum (In CM) from the place it has travelled $t$ seconds after it starts to swing. Here, $t$ is entered in radians.

$$P(t) = -5\cos(2\pi t) + 5$$

What is the first time the pendulum reaches 3.5 CM from the place it was released?

*Round your final answer to the hundredth of a second.*

Ok, so I did this to get the solution:

$$3.5 = -5\cos(2\pi t) +5$$
$$-1.5 = -5\cos(2\pi t)$$
$$0.3 = \cos(2\pi t)$$
$$\cos^{-1}(0.3) = 2\pi t$$
$$\frac{\cos^{-1}(0.3)}{2\pi} = t$$

The fact is this gives me 11.55 seconds to get to 3.5 CM, which does not sound right. Where did I go wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Looks your calculator is in degrees mode. Switch to radians...

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! Make sure you place that answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you're expecting the input to $\cos$ in radians because you have $2\pi$ in $\cos(2\pi t)$. In physics you [always use radians](https://qedinsight.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/why-radian-measure-makes-life-easier-in-mathematics-and-physics/).

However, you can get it to work in degrees with a slight modification: change $2\pi$ to $360$. Don't make it a habit though. Stay away from degrees...